# php string replace not getting as desired

Tags: php

I have a string s follows:

```
Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»Â«msupÂ»Â«miÂ»xÂ«/miÂ»Â«mnÂ»2Â«/mnÂ»Â«/msupÂ»Â«/mathÂ»
```

I want to convert it to:

`<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>`

What I tried is as follows:

```
$text = str_replace("Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»","<math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("«/mathÂ»","</math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("»Â",">", $text);
$text = str_replace("Â«","<", $text);

echo $text;
```

But for my bad luck I am getting the output string as :

```
Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»Â«msupÂ»Â«miÂ»xÂ«/miÂ»Â«mnÂ»2Â«/mnÂ»Â«/msupÂ»Â«/mathÂ»
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Use `preg_replace()`

Comment: @aldrin27 can you post as an answer? then it will be very helpful!! I tried that not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just a couple `str_replace`'s to do...

```
$text = "Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»Â«msupÂ»Â«miÂ»xÂ«/miÂ»Â«mnÂ»2Â«/mnÂ»Â«/msupÂ»Â«/mathÂ»";

$text = str_replace("Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»","<math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("«/mathÂ»","</math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("»Â",">", $text);
$text = str_replace("»",">", $text);
$text = str_replace("Â«","<", $text);
$text = str_replace("«","<", $text);
$text = str_replace("Â","", $text);

echo $text; // outputs <math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>
```

Comment: I got output as <p><math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>3</mn></msup></math></p>

Comment: What do you mean? If you run `Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»Â«msupÂ»Â«miÂ»xÂ«/miÂ»Â«mnÂ»2Â«/mnÂ»Â«/msupÂ»Â«/mathÂ»` through the above PHP, you'll get `<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>`.

Comment: I am writing that into a file. $text = str_replace("Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»","<math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("«/mathÂ»","</math>", $text);
$text = str_replace("»Â",">", $text);
$text = str_replace("»",">", $text);
$text = str_replace("Â«","<", $text);
$text = str_replace("«","<", $text);
$text = str_replace("Â","", $text);

echo $text;

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $text);
fclose($myfile);

Comment: Writing what into a file? Where? Can you post *all* your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **utf8_decode** to remove the Â symbol and replace all the unnecessary values using **str_replace**.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $text = utf8_decode("Â«math xmlns=Â¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathMLÂ¨Â»Â«msupÂ»Â«miÂ»xÂ«/miÂ»Â«mnÂ»2Â«/mnÂ»Â«/msupÂ»Â«/mathÂ»");     
    $text = str_replace("«","<",$text);
    $text =  str_replace("»",">",$text);
    $text = str_replace("xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨","",$text);
    echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```

**Link::**
[Demo with source code in phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$text%20=%20utf8_decode(%22%C3%82%C2%ABmath%20xmlns=%C3%82%C2%A8http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML%C3%82%C2%A8%C3%82%C2%BB%C3%82%C2%ABmsup%C3%82%C2%BB%C3%82%C2%ABmi%C3%82%C2%BBx%C3%82%C2%AB/mi%C3%82%C2%BB%C3%82%C2%ABmn%C3%82%C2%BB2%C3%82%C2%AB/mn%C3%82%C2%BB%C3%82%C2%AB/msup%C3%82%C2%BB%C3%82%C2%AB/math%C3%82%C2%BB%22);%5Cn%20$text%20=%20str_replace(%22%C2%AB%22,%22%3C%22,$text);%5Cn%20$text%20=%20str_replace(%22%C2%BB%22,%22%3E%22,$text);%5Cn%20$text%20=%20str_replace(%22xmlns=%C2%A8http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML%C2%A8%22,%22%22,$text);%5Cn%20echo%20htmlspecialchars($text);%5Cn?%3E)

**Result::**

[image]

Comment: @NeethuRaj. I have updated my solution. You can run the php script it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @NeethuRaj Glad i could help.

Comment: Buddy I am getting output as «math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msup»«mi»x«/mi»«mn»2«/mn»«/msup»«/math». Which is Wrong!!

Comment: @NeethuRaj I updated my answer with the solution in action. See the phpfiddle link

Comment: @NeethuRaj make sure that the order/position of str_replace are the same as my code.